# facebook publish action customization

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I created a "Rent" action for my website, which publishes the action when ever anyone click on the "Rent" button. The action gets published something like 'Sandeep rented a Textbook on BookStreet'; but the link to textbook is to the open graph url(http://samples.ogp.me/238383...) not the url of the textbook actually rented.

I want the action to be published as 'Sandeep rented  from BookStreet'. I think its more of a configuration issue in the open graph object (All the persmissions are being taken appropritely including the publish_actions permission). How do I got about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The action gets published something like 'Sandeep rented a Textbook on BookStreet'; but the link to textbook is to the open graph url(http://samples.ogp.me/238383...) not the url of the textbook actually rented.

And which URL have you given while publishing the action?

> I want the action to be published as 'Sandeep rented from BookStreet'.

So what’s your actual object the action should be taken upon – is it the textbook, or is it just “bookstreet” …?